# .usesFontLeading does not work

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I am trying to wrap
 text into box, and in some guide mentioned this approach:

```
  let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin.union(.usesFontLeading)

  let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
```

I tried and everything works but when i deleted .usesFontLeading text boxes remains same. Nothing changed

[image]

then i tried to delete usesLineFragmentOrigin option and left usesFontleading and i was given that "weird" result

[image]

because xcode says:

> usesFontLeading: Uses the font leading for calculating line heights.

But I did not noticed in result picture the presence of fontLeading option. Maybe I am wrong somewhere? What really does this option?

Comment: try with `let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)` let me know if solves your issue @N.Khasanov

Comment: everything works as it used to be) @Reinier Melian please can you explain me what usesFontLeading option literally does?

Comment: of course you can

Comment: Added as answer

Comment: @ReinierMelian you should add this as an answer. I'll upvote it

Comment: @LanceSamaria I was answered this question already, check was deleted, but if solves your issue I will undelete it

Comment: when I added .usesFontLeading it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to pass options to `boundingRect` method

```
let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)
```

this is what AppleDocs says about the `.usesFontLeading` option

> Uses the font leading for calculating line heights.

for further research https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsstring.drawingoptions

**Testing searching difference**

**This (your original version)**

```
let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin.union(.usesFontLeading)
debugPrint(options)
```

**Prints**

> __C.NSStringDrawingOptions(rawValue: 3)

**This (Correct version)**

```
let optionsArr : [NSStringDrawingOptions] = [.usesFontLeading,.usesLineFragmentOrigin]
debugPrint(optionsArr)
```

**Prints**

> [__C.NSStringDrawingOptions(rawValue: 2),
>   __C.NSStringDrawingOptions(rawValue: 1)]

***As you can see there is some difference***

Comment: then if it Uses the font leading for calculating line heights so why in result picture mentioned above we there is no presence of usesFontLeading?

Comment: @N.Khasanov its seems that union sum rawValue = 1 and rawValue = 2 resulting in rawValue = 3 which is no what we want as I show you in the updated answer

Comment: please, if its the only one difference in log section and there is no difference in appearance then why do we need to apply that option ?

Comment: @N.Khasanov the 2 options we need to use are `.usesFontLeading` and `.usesLineFragmentOrigin`the same as you have in your question originally but what is wrong in your question code is the way you are setting the options, using .union instead of array of `NSStringDrawingOptions`,

Comment: @N.Khasanov did my answer help you finally?

Comment: ok @N.Khasanov your question is about if `.usesFontLeading` do something? is that your question?

Comment: My question is about what exactly doing .usesFontLeading option, and according to docs and right after comparing with result picture it seems that either .usesFontleading works somehowe incorrect or my mind works somehow incorrect in misleading me